# Timestamp in C.

Tags: c, arrays, timestamp

Is there any basic timestamp example in milliseconds or seconds starting from zero ?.

If I have an array of 8-bit unsigned integers:

```
uint8_t array[10];
```

it is somehow possible to store the milliseconds in to the first element, and store the seconds in the second element of the array, as:

array[0] = milliseconds;

array[1] = seconds;

Comment: First of all, you won't fit milliseconds (0-999) into a byte which can have a value of at most 255.

Comment: That's the issue. I have to use an array of uint8_t. Can it be separated in two elements ?. So I can use the first three elements for timestamp as well

Comment: Why do you need to use uint8_t, out of curiosity?

Comment: Use array[0] & array[1] to store milliseconds and the rest to store `time_t` or swap order per endian requirements.

Comment: I'm transferring pixel values from a grayscale image, that represents uint8_t

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would use an array of uint16_t to store the number of milliseconds (or use an even larger type, depending on how large the time value you need to store will be).

Since your comment suggests you can't do that for some reason, I would suggest breaking it up so that the least significant bits are in the first element, and the most significant bits are in the second. For example, if you had a timestamp with a hex value `0x1234`, you could store it as

```
myArray[0] = 0x34;
myArray[1] = 0x12;
```

Note that you could read and write these values as if they were 16 bit values, event though they are in an array of 8-bit values, using a type-casting and pointers, using something along the lines

```
 my16bitValue = ((uint16_t*)myArray)[0];
```

As long as you both read and write this way, the endianness of the processor doesn't matter. As chux points out below, though, if you are accessing memory on boundaries that are not aligned properly (i.e. memory addresses which are not a multiple of the number of bytes in the type), then you may get a segfault, or at least significantly decreased performance, depending on your architecture. There may be a better way, but it is hard to say without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Martin R - Fixed. Thanks

Comment: The infrequent, but subtle problem with `((uint16_t*)myArray)[0]` is that one does not know if the alignment requirements of `uint16_t` work with `array`.  `myArray[0] = 0x34; myArray[1] = 0x12;` gets around this issue, but then endian issues arise.

Comment: So, I can directly point a uint16_t data to a single element in a uint8_t array using type-casting and pointers as I understand ?.

Comment: @OP In select situations yes, but in general no.  Say a `uint16_t` can't go across a 16-bit boundary (1/2 at address 1 and half at address 2) without resetting the CPU.  Since we do not know the 16-bit alignment `array`, this approach fails on platforms that require alignment.  On systems that do allow a byte alignment of a 16-bit word, performance may suffer.  Something like `myArray[0] = ms & 255; myArray[1] = (ms>>8) & 255; myArray[2] = s & 255; myArray[3] = (s>>8) & 255; ... myArray[9] = (s>>56) & 255;` might work.  But this is pedantic.  Maybe John G solution will work in your case.